# Progress dialog shows up AFTER ajax call is finished eventhough its triggered BEFORE

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, progressdialog

hey,
i have a problem with jquery. i'm running a couple of ajax calls and i want to show a progress dialog. however the progress dialog doesnt show up until the ajax code is finished...when it should clearly fire up before any ajax request. i hope you can help me out, this is killing me..
thanks in advance

```
function add() {
     $('#loadingscreen').show(); //SHOWS UP AFTER ALL THE AJAX REQUESTS ARE FINISHED
     $('.tdtrackname').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          url: 'ajax/add.php?query=' + $(this).html(),
          success: function(data) {
             $('#divajax').html(data);
          }
        });
     });
}
```

Comment: If you want a progress dialog why are you using a non asynchronous ajax call?

Comment: because i need the calls to be in order. else the next one gets triggered before the last one is finished

Comment: Just to try something...perhaps the synchronous call is blocking everything? (even the drawing on the screen) and because of this you only see the dialog when the call finished?

Comment: but the drawing on the screen is happening before the sync call...weird

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
function add() {
     $('.tdtrackname').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          async: false,
          url: 'ajax/add.php?query=' + $(this).html(),
          beforeSend: function() { $('#loadingscreen').show(); },
          success: function(data) {
             $('#divajax').html(data);
          }
        });
     });
}
```

Comment: tried this, same thing happens. as soon as all the ajax calls have been made, the loading screen pops up (~5seconds after the function add() is excecuted)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the question, the synchronous call is very likely blocking all operations on the DOM. Your best bet is to re-think how you are requesting and processing your data so that you can do it asynchronously.

Comment: yeah but its not supposed to block something thats launching before right?

Comment: `$.show()` sends a signal to the browser's DOM renderer that it should re-paint the document. The re-paint happens outside of the JavaScript engine. So, the JavaScript engine doesn't wait for the re-paint to occur before continuing on with the AJAX request. Therefore, it _could_ happen that your loading screen shows before the request. But it likely won't since the re-paint is an expensive operation.